# ASP.Net Web Api, odata, pagination on transformed dataset

Tags: database, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using the asp.net web api and odata to paginate my database, the thing is I don't return to the clients the same data representation as in the database:

```
//EF 6 context
public class Context : DbContext 
{
    IDbSet<DbData> DbData {get;set;} 
}

Context _ctx = ...

[EnableQuery(PageSize = 100)]
public IQueryable<Data> Get()
{
    return _ctx.DbData.Select(d => new Data{...}).AsQueryable();
}
```

Although the odata queries work fine (to the client), they are all made in memory, meaning that all `DbData` records are pulled from the database and only then the odata queries are executed.

Is there any way to use data transformation and still have odata queries working in a db level?

Note: Right now I only want to use odata to do pagination.

Note2: The query that I'm making is api/Controller?$top=100&$skip=100

Comment: Normally the query is executed at the database level. What proof that this is not the case ?

Comment: I used sql profiler to check the queries, if I return ctx.DbData they run on the database, but if i transform them, they run in mem

Comment: what is the type of _ctx.DbData ?

Comment: I suppose it is not IQueryable and it is the reason why odata queries are executed in memory

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework? Version number? Is `_ctx.DbData` a `DbSet<>`? Check the type of `_ctx.DbData.Select(d => new Data{...})` (using `GetType` and the `System.Diagnostic.Debug` to write it to the VS output window).

Comment: You don't need to use `AsQueryable()`. If you need it to get your code compiled, so there must be something wrong with your code.

Comment: Why IDbSet and not DbSet ?